# Running CUDA programs on Quadro K620m

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have laptop which has Quadro K620m GPU. I am trying to learn CUDA programming and downloaded the network installer from NVIDIA site.

During CUDA SDK installation, just when its checking the hardware of the machine, it displays

Do you want to Continue?

This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware. You may continue installation, but you will not be able to run CUDA applications.

Any thoughts why this could be happening? In my computer's device manager, I can see NVIDIA Quadro K620m in the display adapter listing.

Thank you.

Comment: This is normal, when the driver packaged in the CUDA installer is "older" than your GPU.  You should retain your current GPU driver, and go ahead with the CUDA toolkit installation, but de-select the option to install the GPU driver.  The one you have should work fine.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. What shoud i do now, as I have installed latest driver with toolkit ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, when the driver packaged in the CUDA installer is "older" than your GPU.

You should retain your current GPU driver, and go ahead with the CUDA toolkit installation, but de-select the option to install the GPU driver.

Your existing driver should work fine.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. What shoud i do now, as I have installed latest driver with toolkit ??